Ubuntu 24.04 and LVM encryption "Waiting for encrypted source device" on recent Intel + kernel 6.6 and above
I installed a brand new Ubuntu 24.04 on an external disk (Samsung SSD X5) with LVM encryption (default configuration)
With default Kernel 6.8.0-45 , on newer Intel platforms, the device don't want to boot, don't ask for password, showing a message "Waiting for encrypted source device"
With older computer, I am able to boot, and install Mainline, and I tried many different kernels :

6.11.0
6.8.0-45 (Ubuntu default)
6.6.51
6.5.11
6.2.0

Here is the result for each platform :

Intel i9-9980HK - Coffee Lake (9th generation) : Working with all kernels
Intel i7-1165G7 - Tiger Lake (11th generation) : Working with all kernels
Intel i7-12700H - Alder Lake (12th generation) : 6.2 is booting but don't have Wifi, 6.5 no issue. 6.6 and above do not boot
Intel® Core™ Ultra 7 155H - Meteor Lake (Ultra Series 1) : Same as Alder Lake platform

So it seems that Kernel 6.6 brake something with recent Intel support.
